# Calling the `getDiscountRates` function to 'main` function

Tags: c++, calling-convention

The title speaks for itself. I tried adding the `quantity` to the prototype parameter, but I think the quantity multiplies itself when I run the program. I also tried adding the `DiscountRates` to the prototype, but that didn't do anything either.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Writing the prototype*/

double getDiscountRates();

int main()
{
    int quantity, DiscountRates;
    float price;
    double  pretotal, totalAfterDiscount, discountamount;
    
    
    /* Input Statement */
    
    cout << "Company Order Cost Calculator" << endl << endl;
    cout << "How many items does the customer want? ";
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << "How much does each item cost? $";
    cin >> price;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    
    /* Calling the second function */
    
    DiscountRates = getDiscountRates();
    pretotal = quantity * price;
    discountamount = pretotal * DiscountRates;
    totalAfterDiscount = pretotal - discountamount;
    
    /* Display result */
    
    cout << endl << "Total Before Discount: $" << pretotal << endl;
    cout << "Discount Amount: $" << discountamount << endl;
    cout << "Total After Discount: $" << totalAfterDiscount << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

/* Writing the second function */

double getDiscountRates()
{
    int DiscountRates, quantity;
    
    if (quantity <= 8)
    {
        DiscountRates = 0;
    }
    else if ((quantity >= 9) && (quantity <= 12))
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.10;
    }    
    else if ((quantity >= 13) && (quantity <= 25))
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.15;
    }
    else
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.20;
    }
    
    return DiscountRates;
}
```

Comment: "I tried adding the `quantity` to the prototype parameter" Would you mind showing the code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDiscountRates` function uses the indeterminate value of uninitialized local variable `quantity`.

It seem you want to pass the value of `quantity` from the `main` function.

You should add an argument to pass that.

Also you should use `double` for the local variable `DiscountRates`. Otherwise, the value will be truncated to an integer and the result will be zero for all cases.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Writing the prototype*/

double getDiscountRates(int quantity); // add argument

int main()
{
    // use proper type for DiscountRates
    int quantity;
    float price;
    double DiscountRates, pretotal, totalAfterDiscount, discountamount;
    
    
    /* Input Statement */
    
    cout << "Company Order Cost Calculator" << endl << endl;
    cout << "How many items does the customer want? ";
    cin >> quantity;
    cout << "How much does each item cost? $";
    cin >> price;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    
    /* Calling the second function */
    
    DiscountRates = getDiscountRates(quantity); // pass the value of quantity
    pretotal = quantity * price;
    discountamount = pretotal * DiscountRates;
    totalAfterDiscount = pretotal - discountamount;
    
    /* Display result */
    
    cout << endl << "Total Before Discount: $" << pretotal << endl;
    cout << "Discount Amount: $" << discountamount << endl;
    cout << "Total After Discount: $" << totalAfterDiscount << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

/* Writing the second function */

double getDiscountRates(int quantity) // add argument
{
    double DiscountRates; // remove the local variable quantity and use proper type for DiscountRates
    
    if (quantity <= 8)
    {
        DiscountRates = 0;
    }
    else if ((quantity >= 9) && (quantity <= 12))
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.10;
    }    
    else if ((quantity >= 13) && (quantity <= 25))
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.15;
    }
    else
    {
        DiscountRates = 0.20;
    }
    
    return DiscountRates;
}
```